# ARKit + SceneKit: Light rapidly increases number of polygons

Tags: 3d, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, light

I'm creating AR app with SceneKit and ARKit. When I add light sources to the scene, it increases the number of polygons almost 3 times. This leads to huge lags in my case. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: How are you checking the number of polygons? Are you sure that the number you're looking at isn't the number of draw calls or some other metric?

Comment: Yes, maybe. I'm checking most right value at the bottom of the screen in scenekit standard debugview

Comment: Even if this value is a number drawcalls, still scene lags increase corresponding to this number. This value has triangle as icon

Comment: In the SceneKit statistics, the rhombus is the number of draw calls, the triangle is the number of polygons, and the dot is the number of vertices.

Comment: If anyone is going to be able to help answer why your scene is rendering slowly you need to provide more information so that we're able to reproduce it or at the very least understand what's happening. For example: what geometry do you have in your scene? How are you adding lights to the scene? How are those lights configured (distances, number of samples, shadows, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

This problem may happen if you're using Forward Rendering.

In such case, when you have some object that is lit by few lights then it will be rendered once for every light (there're exceptions but let's ignore them for now). Depending on the number and influence(size) of you lights your scene geometry can be rendered even dozens of times.

What can be done:

- Use `Deferred` rendering instead of `Forward` one. `Deferred` rendering overcomes this issue and you can use even thousands of lights.
- Use less lights but make them bigger, so they still light up your scene.
- Add `Ambient` lighting so you don't need `real` light everywhere. Use real lights only to make something brighter.
- Look at the radius and/or bounding box of your lights and fix them if needed. They are used to optimize rendering so if a light doesn't touch some geometry you can ignore it. It's possible that you don't have those data so every light touches every geometry.
- Split your level geometry into smaller chunks. This is tricky because by splitting geometry you get more render batches but you can also get less overlapping between geometry and lights. This should be done based on your specific level and lighting setup.